# Get file handle to running executable

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I am trying to call GetFileInformationByHandle on the executable of my own running program. This means I'll need to get a file handle to the .exe that started my program. Is there any way to do this?

Failing that, is there any way to get the nFileIndexHigh and nFileIndexLow for a running executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is a way to do this. I hope this helps:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//declare a BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION structure
BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION fileinfo;

int main()
{
    // clear everything in the structure, this is optional
    ZeroMemory(&fileinfo, sizeof(BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION));

    // obtain a handle to the file, in this case the file
    // must be in the same directory as your application
    HANDLE myfile = NULL;
    myfile = CreateFileA("example.exe",0x00,0x00,NULL,
                         OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);

    // if we managed to obtain the desired handle
    if(myfile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //try to fill the structure with info regarding the file
        if(GetFileInformationByHandle(myfile, &fileinfo))
        {
            // Ex: show the serial number of the volume the file belongs to
            cout << endl << hex << fileinfo.dwVolumeSerialNumber << endl;
        }
        // you should close the handle once finished
        CloseHandle(myfile);
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know the file is called `example.exe`?

Comment: I don't, that's why I called it "example.exe". :OP

Comment: I don't think you understand @bobbogo. I think he means, how would you get hold of the file name of the .exe given that a user could run it from anywhere they liked. To which the answer is `GetModuleFileName`.

Comment: I understood the question, and the answer is this is an example. I am not getting paid to write the full code down. 
I think the guy who asked about it, got the idea and that's what I care about.
If you want to help more then write down your code and stop just naming windows APIs.
Thank you.

Comment: @David you don't understand. I don't need the file name, I need the handle to the file. Please read for comprehension before trying to answer. This is the accepted answer because it actually answers my question. The example was good enough I could change it to fit my needs.

Answer (score 5):

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileNameEx(   
   __in      HANDLE hProcess,
   __in_opt  HMODULE hModule,
   __out     LPTSTR lpFilename,
   __in      DWORD nSize );
```

Second parameter should be NULL and you will get the name of the current executable.

EDIT:

Then open the file.

Comment: That's not what I asked. I need the file handle so I can call GetFileInformationByHandle. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @Sparafusile even if he didn't understand your question it is not excuse for being rude.

Comment: Misread the question.  I won't answer any of yours anymore, so don't worry.

Comment: @Sparafusile: With `GetModuleFileNameEx` you can get full path to your executable and then open it. +1 to James

Comment: 1. Use `GetModuleFileName()` (the docs say _To retrieve the name of a module in the current process, use the GetModuleFileName function. This is more efficient and more reliable than calling GetModuleFileNameEx with a handle to the current process_). 2. Then `OpenFile()`.

Comment: @James i think that it should work. I even prefer this solution over mine.

Comment: @DReJ: That was my intention.  Didn't think it was a big stretch to that, but apprently it was.

Comment: @bobbogo `CreateFile`, not `OpenFile`

Comment: @Andrey Ooooh, I'm only 10 years out of date :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get path to executable. Then open and here is your handle.

Comment: Every time I CreateFile or OpenFile on my executable my application crashes.

Comment: @Sparafusile trick is in picking correct values of `dwDesiredAccess` and `dwShareMode`

Comment: and do you happen to know what values those are?

Answer (score 0):

GetModuleHandle is the solution here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199(VS.85).aspx

If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleHandle returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file).

Comment: As I know `GetModuleHandle` returns a handle to module mapped in memory, but not actually to file. In case the parameter is NULL it will return pointer to ImageBase.

Comment: This returns an HMODULE. Calling GetFileInformationByHandle with the return value causes the error "The handle is invalid."

Comment: @sparafusile: `HMODULE` is merly an alias for `HANDLE`, there real point is that its not a **file** handle but a mapped memory handle

Comment: @Necrolis and HANDLE is just a DWORD, I got it. Either way, the result of GetModuleHandle can't be passed to OpenFile without creating an error.

Comment: Looks like @DeadMG needs to go back to Win32 school to learn the difference between a handle to a file and a handle to a module.

Comment: Never went. It's the WinAPI's own fault for weak typing anyway :P

Comment: @DeadMG It is a bit befuddling at times, keeping track of just what you can and can't do with a handle. There are benefits though - I'm thinking of MsgWaitForMultipleObjects for example.

Comment: @David: That's what inheritance is for.

Comment: @DeadMG Agreed, but for an OS API then inheritance isn't an option.

Comment: @David: Why not? I didn't say they should use virtual functions.

Comment: @DeadMG Windows API is 25 years old. Inheritance requires OOP. COM had not been invented. What tools and languages could they have used back in 1985?

Comment: @David: That's because it's an *old* API, not because it's an *OS* API. More importantly, exceptions are part of Win32- why not inheritance?

Comment: @DeadMG Yes you are right. It's the age rather than the fact that it's the API to an OS. But what tools? COM?